# Installing Dell v313 printer/scanner on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, printer, ubuntu-12.04, scanner

I've been searching for hours now, trying to find a working driver for a Dell 313 printer/scanner (v310 - 510 series) on Ubuntu 12.04. But I can't seem to find a working one.

I really need this to work, but I'm not keen on installing another OS.

I've installed Ubuntu on this PC for someone who didn't want Windows XP after the support stopped. Vista is not the ideal solution I'm afraid. As it was the original OS on the system, but it ran awefully slow.

Is there someone who can help me installing some kind of driver for this printer/scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me on Linux Mint 15, should work on ubuntu.

First download the driver from Dell:

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?driverId=R293768

Unfortunately there seems to be a newline too much, but as mentioned by David, these printers are rebranded Lexmark printers so you can follow this guide:
http://archbird.blogspot.no/2012/04/fix-error-blank-line-installing-lexmark.html

In short (be sure the replace the lexmark names with dell):

```
tar -xvvf instarchive_all --lzma
ar x lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb control.tar.gz
tar xf control.tar.gz
gedit control
```

Now edit the control file so that the last line looks something like this

> Description: Dell Drivers Package

Be sure to end the file with a newline.
Now repeat the steps above in reverse order:

```
tar cfz control.tar.gz ./control ./postinst ./prerm ./preinst 
ar r lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb control.tar.gz
sudo dpkg --install lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
```

The scanner worked after installing xsane.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I didn't change the names in the config to dell, that was what I missed :-D

Answer (score 0):

For slightly older version of Ubuntu, but it may help.  The first link, someone says it is a rebranded Lexmark S301 thru Lexmark S305 printer.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1937177

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867935&highlight=dell+v313

Or buy a new one that has Linux support listed on the tin.  I have had a number of HP multifunction printers with really great driver support.